# fancybox doesn't show overlay at bottom of page if popup is longer than the original page

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am using Fancybox on a site, and it's all going well except in one case...

If the page fits on a single screen and the popup window is larger than a screen then the overlay is only shown for the height of the original single screen and everything below that has no overflow.

So it seems the overlay is applied at 100% of the page height BEFORE the popup window is generated. So is there anyway of regenerating the overlay once the popup has been rendered? Or any other way of fixing it.

Unfortunately It's on an internal project so I can't send a link, but hopefully my description makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely are using fancybox v1.3.4 or below since this behavior (bug) doesn't show up in v2.x.

The quickest workaround is adding a CSS inline declaration AFTER you loaded your fancybox CSS file. This should do the trick:

```
<style type="text/css">
 #fancybox-overlay { position: fixed !important; }
</style>
```